# Add user to login to an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Im a newb to AWS, so please go easy on me.  We currently just spun up a custom Windows 10 instance in AWS.  I was able to login via RDP successfully, but I'd like to create a new user within the instance so they can login with a different user account using RDP.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, After your response to my first, I think I see what you are asking. Plase watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgk2w3dQGSo

Download the RDP. Save it. You can then Edit the .rdp and enter the user name and password you created in Windows.

You can create users in the User Management Console in Windows. Ensure they have the rights needed (Remote Desktop User, Administrator, etc).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Once an Amazon EC2 Windows instance has been launched, it is just a normal Windows computer.

Therefore, you should use use the standard Admin tools to create the user on the Windows computer, with their own username and password.

It is also recommended that you change the random `Administrator` password after initial login, or (even better) connect the instance to Active Directory or whatever standard authentication system your company uses.

Answer (score 0):

Technoob here. I just figured out why all of you are having trouble. You need to go to the security group the machine is a part of and open port 3389 to your public IP address (ipchicken.com works). Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from another computer then you have to change the inbound rules.
Go to the security groups of your instance. Go to the inbound rules. Add ipv4 and ipv6 as a new rule and apply it. Download the RDP File and try to connect again. It worked for me.